# How can I limit the rotation angle of the object?

Tags: unity, c#

At the top

```
float speed = 1.0f;
float rotationAngle = 45;
```

In Update :

```
private void Update()
    {
            if (Mathf.Approximately(transform.localPosition.y, 7))
            {
                float rotationY = rotationAngle * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speedRot);
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, rotationY, 0));
            }
    }
```

but it's just rotating nonstop at the same direction.

I need it to rotate for example in the limited range of 45 to both sides like a ping pong from side to side. and optional to make it to rotate in limited angle/s for all axis but now for the Y how to limit it like a ping pong to rotate 45 degrees to the right then back to the left and so on nonstop but in limited angle/s.

Answer (score 1):

`Transform.Rotate()` does not rotate set the Transform to a specific rotation. It rotates the Transform by a given amount. In other words, you're telling Unity "increase the Y-axis rotation by `rotationY` degrees" instead of "set the Y-axis rotation to `rotationY` degrees".

It sounds like what you want is just to set the rotation:

```
float rotationY = rotationAngle * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speedRot);
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, rotationY, 0);
```

If you want the GameObject to rotate around its initial orientation:

```
Quaternion startRotation;
void Start() {
    startRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void Update() {
    if (Mathf.Approximately(transform.localPosition.y, 7)) {
        float rotationY = rotationAngle * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speedRot);
        Quaternion delta = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, rotationY, 0));
        transform.rotation = startRotation * delta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the object is first rotating facing the opposite direction by 180 degrees before making the rotationY ? When I'm running the game the object just changing direction at once by 180 degrees then it start rotating by the rotationAngle.  I tried this but it didn't change much : transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, rotationY, transform.rotation.z);

Comment: For testing I set the rotationAngle to 10

Comment: @Rongalgal See my updated answer.

Comment: @Rongalgal Did I answer your question? If so, please don't forget to mark this as the answer.